# Can tmux and a SSH-client on Windows be more integrated?

Tags: ssh, putty, tmux

I am using `tmux` on my Debian server and PuTTY on Windows.  This works as expected, but sometimes I wish, to have a more Windows like feeling when working via SSH, eg. have separate windows for the tmux tabs and use Alt-Tab or the mouse to switch between them.

I have found several PuTTY alternatives that offer tabbed interfaces and deeper Windows integration, but ideally I would like to keep running tmux and only have some more comfort when accessing the system from my Windows PC.

Can you point me in what directions to look, besides remotely accessing an XServer on the linux box

Answer (score 1):

What about something like [mRemoteNG](http://www.mremoteng.org/)?